# Postgres: is this an equivalent rewrite of OVERLAPS predicate?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgres15

For some reason, Postgres (15.3) isn't using a multicolumn index on `(an_id, start_ts, end_ts)` when `OVERLAPS` operator is used in a WHERE predicate:

```sql
WHERE (start_ts, end_ts) OVERLAPS (input_ts_start, input_ts_end)
```

With the following rewrite though, the planner *can* use the above multicolumn index. **But, is above `OVERLAPS` predicate equivalent to this?**

```sql
WHERE input_ts_start < end_ts AND input_ts_end > start_ts
```

Presuming that both `_ts` pairs are internally ordered (`start_ts < end_ts` and `input_ts_start < input_ts_end`) is the 2nd version equivalent? ([Postgres' source is more elaborate since it handles cases where any two `_ts` pairs might have to be swapped](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/22ff5c9d78b9c23622de2cf0730cec85266a7596/src/backend/utils/adt/date.c/#L1817). It also takes care of NULLs.)

Having `input_ts_end` as `'infinity'::timestamp` also works with the index. Am I missing anything else?

---

From the [documentation on `OVERLAPS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html):

> In addition to these functions, the SQL OVERLAPS operator is supported:
>
> ```
> (start1, end1) OVERLAPS (start2, end2)
> (start1, length1) OVERLAPS (start2, length2)
> ```
>
> This expression yields true when two time periods (defined by their endpoints) overlap, false when they do not overlap. The endpoints can be specified as pairs of dates, times, or time stamps; or as a date, time, or time stamp followed by an interval. When a pair of values is provided, either the start or the end can be written first; OVERLAPS automatically takes the earlier value of the pair as the start. Each time period is considered to represent the half-open interval start <= time < end, unless start and end are equal in which case it represents that single time instant. This means for instance that two time periods with only an endpoint in common do not overlap.

Comment: The range-types are much easier to use, and also include indexing and constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your additional assumptions, your rewrite should be identical to `OVERLAPS`. PostgreSQL does not support index scans for `OVERLAPS`; one of the reasons must be that `OVERLAPS` swaps end points.

You might consider using range types and the `&&` operator, which can be supported by a GiST index.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. 

I'll look into whether `ts[tz]range]` would be any faster, since this is a 200 million rows table, and I read that "[with big tables, a GiST index on a range type is _most probably_ faster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59083)" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Right, only the experiment can tell. What is certain is that GiST indexes are more expensive during `UPDATE`.